# Android Settings STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN

Tags: android, system, root

I am building a system app and I need to force the setting Stay Awake on. To do that I am running this code:        `Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.Global.STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN, 0);`

which is returning the following error:

`Setting stay_on_while_plugged_in has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, value is unchanged.`

I understand that they moved it from Settings.System to Settings.Global but I AM using Settings.Global. I have the permissions:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>`

So there should be no problem. Why can't I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.Global.STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN, 0);
```

;-)

Comment: Oh man. I can't believe I didn't see the second Settings.System there. I am clearly out of it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You said you're using this code :

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.Global.STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN, 0);
```

But you should use this code :

```
Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.Global.STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN, 0);
```